# Trouble deploying django app to azure web app

Tags: python, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have never deployed a django project to a web app. I usually just build them for fun using localhost. However, I now have one I am trying to deploy to an Azure Web App but keep hitting a brick wall. The deployments within Azure are all successful, but when I visit the app domain I still only see the basic  page ["Hey, Python developers!"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnu8j.png)

I have read through some existing documentation and made sure to include a web.config file as well as using a wsgi.py file. Additionally, I have updated my settings.py file to include the appropriate ALLOWED_HOSTS. Below  is my django folder structure:

```
|.venv
|naviwebsite
   |accounts
   |naviwebsite
       |settings.py
       |wsgi.py
   |manage.py
|requirements.txt
|web.config
```

Additionally, below is my web.config file:

```html
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="naviwebsite.wsgi.application"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python377x64\python.exe|D:\home\python377x64\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The views and forms that make up my django app are all located within the accounts folder. Has anyone else come across similar issues when deploying their django app to an Azure Linux Web App? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Are you deploying to a Windows or Linux App Service? The Linux App Service doesn't use a web.config file that's for IIS (Windows). Note: Azure doesn't officially support Python on the Windows App Service. Have a look through the VS Code [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux-01)

Comment: I went through these steps prior but still did not have any success. I got so frustrated, I ended up deploying my web app with Heroku. It is just a more painless method for hosting your web app. Would still like to learn how to do this within Azure still.

Comment: https://stories.mlh.io/deploying-a-basic-django-app-using-azure-app-services-71ec3b21db08

Comment: I actually followed that walkthrough step-by-step and ran into the issue. I think I ran into the issue when configuring the gunicorn startup task. They don't go over it in the walkthrough, and wasn't able to find what I needed elsewhere.